# How to pass and put variable from a php page into a another page(form)?

Tags: php, html, forms, parameter-passing

I working on two pages, a first one which has a form with three fields: name, email and message). This page will send these data to a second page, that will validate if those fields meet the criteria.

If on the second page, any of those fields does not meet the criteria, I want to redirect to the first page (or a third php one), fill the form with previous information and tell the user to correct the fields properly.

I'm strugling to send the data form the second page to the first (or third) one. Does anyone knows a good way to do it?

Here's my code:

First page - contato.html

```
<form action="validate.php" method="POST" name="emailform">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="nome" placeholder="Type your name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="type your@email.com here">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" maxlength="300" id="message" name="mensagem" placeholder="Leave your message." ></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send message" onclick="alert('Thank you!')" ></form>
```

Second Page - validate.php

```
if(isset($_POST['nome'])) $nome = $_POST['nome'];
if(isset($_POST['email'])) $email_visitante = $_POST['email'];
if(isset($_POST['mensagem'])) $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

// if does not meet the criteria, redirect to contato.html and update the form with the info
if(empty($nome)){
    Header("location:contato.html"); 
}
if(empty($email_visitante)){
    Header("location:contato.html");
}
if(empty($mensagem)){
    Header("location:contato.html");
}
// check for letters and space only
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$nome)) {
    Header("location:contato.html");
}
// check if e-mail address is well-formed
if (!filter_var($email_visitante, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    Header("location:contato.php");
}
```

Does anyone knows how to do it? Either sending to a third page or redirecting to the first one (and fill the form in again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use sessions and store data there in one page and access in another, here is a small usage

```
<?php
// page 1
session_start();
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["nome"] = $nome;
$_SESSION["email"] = $email_visitante;
$_SESSION["mensagem"] = $mensagem;

<?php
// page 2|3|N - any other page
session_start();
// Get session variables
$nome = $_SESSION["nome"];
$email_visitante = $_SESSION["email"];
$mensagem = $_SESSION["mensagem"];
```

Comment: You don't have to use Sessions.  Avoid if possible.

Comment: Please post your answer with no session usage, I am interested with it too

Comment: @Progrock yeah, if you could share your solution without session, I am interested

Comment: As this form is short, if values fail validation you could display errors and ask the user to use their back button.  If the values pass validation, pass them to another function to do whatever you wish with them, and then redirect the user.  Longer forms, multi-page forms, and error hand holding increases complexity.  But you can just embed previously collected values in hidden fields.  Session management can increase complexity and overhead.

Comment: If you put some values to session, take on other pages and delete them, does it increase complexity and overhead? Then why is the session created in php?
If you validate inputs from first page, and put the values in hidden inputs on second page, what will happen if user edits hidden input values? In this case you have to validate them one more time, and you will have to validate them as many times as many pages you have. So I think this is much more difficult to manage than session storage

Comment: Validating them again isn't that much of a hassle.  What if a session drops out or is randomly purged?  When do you clear the session?  Personally I try and keep session storage to a minimum and only tokens.  You could store data client side, if you want it to be tamper proof, encrypt/hash it.  Sessions aren't needed for the OP's example.  A form is repopulated when clicking back.  Client side validation could reduce round trips.  Sure sessions could be a solution, but you do not have to use them.

Comment: As a back end  developer I never trust client side validation

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that upon any failed validation you are using a redirect.  Alternatively you can display an error message to the user: suggesting they need to correct their input by going back a page (browser back).

When forms get longer users need some hand holding with error correction.  Their errors need to be clearly indicated with a message alongside as to how they can fix it.

Avoiding using the 'browser back' method above it's common to have the form send to its own url. I've included an example below.

By doing this you can repopulate the form with posted values upon error and add error feedback. You must be careful to escape user input in this situation.

I've added a generic error feedback notice.  Which isn't that helpful in its current form.  You could improve upon this by adjusting the validation code to return an array of error notices and use that within your form for more targeted error feedback.  You could also add - all fields are required - text to help the user.

Upon successful validation that's when to redirect the user to a confirmation page.  This can prevent form resubmissions.

Your name regex pattern in its current form will not allow hyphens or apostrophes. I haven't changed it below.  Do bear this in mind. "Michael O'leary" would be faced with an error and likely not understand why.  You need to be careful when using strict rules for user input.  Also this will reject some unicode.

You also need to escape user input appropriately.  Note that you may be satisfied that the name and email after validation follows a particular pattern, but becareful of raw user input. The message text is passed on raw after validation.

```
<?php
$nome            = $_POST['nome']     ?? null;
$email_visitante = $_POST['email']    ?? null;
$mensagem        = $_POST['mensagem'] ?? null;
$feedback        = null;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(validate($nome, $email_visitante, $mensagem) !== false) {
        process($nome, $email_visitante, $mensagem);
        // Redirect to success/thankyou/confirmation page.
        header('location:success.html');
        exit;
    }
    // This is a generic message, could this be more helpful?
    $feedback = 'Your form has errors.  Please correct them.';
}
form($nome, $email_visitante, $mensagem, $feedback);

function process($nome, $email_visitante, $mensagem) {
    // do something with your values.
}

function validate($nome, $email_visitante, $mensagem) {
    if(empty($nome)) {
        return false;
    }
    if(empty($email_visitante)){
        return false;
    }
    if(empty($mensagem)){
        return false;
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$nome)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!filter_var($email_visitante, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

function form($nome = null, $email_visitante = null, $mensagem = null, $feedback = null) {
?>
    <?= $feedback ?>
    <form action='' method='POST' name='emailform'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='name'>Your name:</label>
            <input type='text' id='name' name='nome' value='<?= htmlspecialchars($nome) ?>'>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='email'>Your email address:</label>
            <input type='text' id='email' name='email' value='<?= htmlspecialchars($email_visitante) ?>'>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='message'>Your message:</label>
            <textarea class='form-control' cols='30' rows='10' maxlength='300' id='message' name='mensagem'><?= htmlspecialchars($mensagem) ?></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send message'>
        </div>
    </form>
<?php
}
```